# How to specify absolute path to a dll on delphi?

Tags: delphi, dll, path, absolute

Is there a way to specify an absolute path to a dll file on delphi ?

Let´s say that I want to use a spcific version of a library and wish to have this dll on my application directory.

I don´t want the application to use the dll contained at any of the path directories .

Comment: Did you read the documentation for [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: The answer depends a great deal on information you haven't provided. How are you loading the DLL? What Windows version? (It differs between them.) Are you referring to a system DLL (one that is part of Windows) or one of your own or a third-party vendor? (The answer is different based in part on that information.) You'll need to be more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system already looks in the application directory by default, that is the first place it always looks.  It is only when the DLL is not in the application directory that you then need to deal with absoute paths, system search paths, etc.